# Python 2to3 Script Not Working - Unicode Error

Tags: python, python-2to3

I found a repo with lots of Python2 files that includes a script to convert them to Python 3. However I get the following error when I run it:

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

The only change I have made is to add the path to `2to3` rather then just having `2to3` since that is not in my path.

Any suggestions for how to get it working please?

```
import os

def makepython3():
    """This is a script to transform all the solutions into 
    Python 3 solutions."""
    files = os.listdir('exercises')

    exfolder = 'exercises'
    ex3folder = 'exercisespy3'

    if not os.path.exists(ex3folder):
        os.mkdir(ex3folder)

    for f in files:
        os.system('cp {} {}'.format(exfolder+os.sep+f, ex3folder+os.sep+f))
        if f.endswith('.py'):
            os.system('"C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py" -w -n --no-diffs {}'.format(ex3folder+os.sep+f))

    print('All done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    makepython3()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
os.system('"C:\Users\HP\....
              ^-- interpreted as a \U unicode escape
```

Try using a raw string:

```
os.system(r'"C:\Users\HP\....
```

`\U` escape sequence was introduced in python 3, which explains that the script worked in python 2. But raw strings should *always* be used when dealing with literal windows paths.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `os.path.sep` together with `os.path.join` to build the path instead of a hardcoded string.

```py
from os.path import join, sep

windows_exe_path = join(
    sep, 
    "C:" + sep, 
    "Users", sep, 
    "HP", sep, 
    "AppData", sep, 
    "Local", sep,
    "Programs", sep, 
    "Python", sep 
    "Python37-32", sep, 
    "Tools", sep,
    "scripts", sep, 
    "2to3.py",
)
```

Otherwise a `/` will also work.

```py
windows_exe_path = "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Tools/scripts/2to3.py"
```